# BS4 is not defined

Tags: python, windows, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create the following variable in my Python shell app:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(offSpring.text, 'lxml')
```

However, it keeps returning an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bs4' is not defined
```

I have already installed bs using the "pip install bs" command.

Any ideas as to why this isn't working correctly?

Comment: Did you `import bs4`?

Comment: yup still giving me the error

Comment: Restart another shell

Comment: How are you importing the module?

Comment: Ah no worries I've fixed it!

Comment: @KobeRichardson-Jones How did you fix it?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: I restarted the shell and ran the code through it again after importing bs4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(offSpring.text, 'lxml')
```